# Facing issue in deploying opencv django application in AWS

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed a simple object detection application using opencv, python3 and tensorflow using cpu.

I have converted as web services and the "GET" request runs locally well. It initiates the camera for live video streaming.

Then I have deployed the  app in AMazon instance using Elastic Beanstalk .

the request is running but it takes too much time and it says memory insufficient error.

the aws log says the error adn  i tried running simple opencv code to open laptop camera. but the log says NO VIDEO CAMERA FOUND IN 0..

Please anyone help me out..

I have referred many Stackoverflows solutions , but none helped me out

I changed the settings of .ebextensions  config file  and many other options

But could not get solutions.

This is my code on my remote machine, these solutions I found on stackOverflow to solve this issues, but it shown me error as No video device found:

```
def detect_video(video, yolo, all_classes):
    #video_path = os.path.join(video)
    video_path=0
    #video_path='rtsp://18.218.165.134:22'
    #video_path='detection@ip-172-31-28-185'
    #video_path='/dev/video0'
    #video_path='localhost:8089'
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture()
    camera.open(video_path)
```

Similarly then I converted it into application and servered as amazon Web service through Get request, then too I got Same error log while running the request:

I am pasting the error log :

[Tue Jan 08 04:54:01.416561 2019] [:error] [pid 3640] Not Found: /

2019-01-08 04:55:35.167982: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

2019-01-08 04:55:50.231771: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 18874368 exceeds 10% of system memory.

2019-01-08 04:55:50.278867: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 18874368 exceeds 10% of system memory.

2019-01-08 04:55:50.325008: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 18874368 exceeds 10% of system memory.

2019-01-08 04:55:50.370483: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 18874368 exceeds 10% of system memory.

2019-01-08 04:55:50.415272: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 18874368 exceeds 10% of system memory.

[Tue Jan 08 04:57:15.748559 2019] [core:error] [pid 3642] [client 103.16.202.28:37936] End of script output before headers: application.py

Comment: You need to show some code. How are you telling OpenCV to open a camera *on the client*, rather than the server?

Comment: Hi daniel , I passed through the ip address and rtcp port

Comment: `code` def detect_video(video, yolo, all_classes):                                                                                     

    #video_path = os.path.join(video)
    video_path=0
    #video_path='rtsp://18.218.165.134:22'

    #video_path='detection@ip-172-31-28-185'
    #video_path='/dev/video0'
    #video_path='localhost:8089'
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture()
    camera.open(video_path)

Comment: But that can't *possibly* work. OpenCV has no way of knowing about or getting to the camera on the client machine. You need to use some kind of JS code to open the camera via the browser and stream it to the server.

Comment: Like Socket programming ... I need to have client server module...

Comment: Or else I need some solution to AWS web service requests  were it shows Memory allocation error

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means.

Comment: Okies.Thanks... JS means Java script code.. Can you share some sample links or codes to refer if possible